# Voice dictation (speech recognition) aborted/stopped after .speakUtterance or sound

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I have an UITextField and a function in order to detect some patterns in my textfield after all editing events. 
When my function detect a pattern, my app plays a sound and `.speakUtterance`.

```
    func playSound() {

    let audioFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("G", ofType: "wav")

    if audioFilePath != nil {

        let audioFileUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(audioFilePath!)

        audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileUrl)
        audioPlayer.play()

    } else {
    }}
```

However, when the Voice dictation of the keyboard is listening and my app plays a sound or speak an utterance, the voice dictation is stopped. 
How to avoid that ? Thanks for you help